# Deadlock when CODES table has 41900 rows

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I'm having a deadlock accessing the same table from two different jobs. I'm testing it on a SQL SERVER 2012 Enterprise edition.

Running SQL Profiler I get this graph:

[image]

You can find the SQL Server Profiler log here: http://pastebin.com/bxcwy7RX

It seems there is a problem with two stored procedures. `GetCode`:

```
SET @code = (SELECT TOP 1 CODE
             FROM CODES 
             WHERE CODE_LEVEL = @aggregationLevel AND COMMISIONING_FLAG = 255
             order by ID_CODE)
```

With this other statement in stored procedure `ReadCodeAuto`:

```
UPDATE CODES SET
      COMMISIONING_FLAG = @commValue
    , SOURCE = 'PLS'
    , USERNAME = ''
    , TIMESPAN = SYSDATETIME() 
WHERE (CODE = @code) AND 
       CODE_LEVEL = @aggregationLevel
```

But the strange thing think is that I get this deadlock when on `CODES` there are around of 41900 rows.

I don't have any transaction inside both stored procedures. And on SQL Server activity monitor I see that process 5& (`GetCode`) has a WRITE LOG wait type, SUSPENDED task state, and UPDATE command.

Do you know how can I fix this problem?

If you need more info, please tell me.

## UPDATE:

Indexes:
**CODES_IS_COMM_IX**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CODES_IS_COMM_IX] ON [dbo].[CODES]
(
    [IS_TRANSMITTED] ASC,
    [COMMISIONING_FLAG] ASC
)
WITH
(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**CODES_IS_TRANS_COMM_FLAG_IX**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CODES_IS_TRANS_COMM_FLAG_IX] ON [dbo].[CODES]
(
    [IS_TRANSMITTED] ASC,
    [COMMISIONING_FLAG] ASC
)
INCLUDE
(
    [ID_CODE],
    [CODE_LEVEL],
    [CODE],
    [TIMESPAN],
    [USERNAME],
    [SOURCE]
)
WITH
(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**ID_CODE_ASC_IX**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ID_CODE_ASC_IX] ON [dbo].[CODES]
(
    [ID_CODE] ASC
)
INCLUDE
(
    [CODE_LEVEL],
    [CODE]
)
WITH
(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**PK_CODES_1**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CODES] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CODES_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CODE_LEVEL] ASC,
    [CODE] ASC
)
WITH
(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I don't change isolation level, so I think is default.

I run this sql to get it:

```
SELECT CASE transaction_isolation_level 
WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncommitted' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted' 
WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable' 
WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable' 
WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
where session_id = @@SPID
```

And it is `ReadCommitted`.

About `ROWLOCK` options, I have removed all hints like `WITH(NOLOCK)` and `HINT(ROWLOCK)`.

And now I see this on SQL Server monitor activity:

[image]

I'm this is another lock that I see in one of my runs:

[image]

There is a `LCK_M_IX`.

I get three indexes with the same object id:
[image]

All data [here](http://pastebin.com/PR8Wwes8).

Comment: Some things to check whenever there are deadlocks - what indexes are involved? What are your page and row locking options for affected indexes (including CI)? What's your isolation level?

Comment: @JNK I have updated my question with more information. But, I don't understand what you mean with: `What are your page and row locking options for affected indexes (including CI)?`. Thanks.

Comment: On indexes you set "Allow Page Locks" and "Allow Row Locks" as options. If those are OFF then then entire index gets locked.

Comment: One thing I see right away is you have redundant indexes which is not gonna help...

Comment: This is the first time I work with SQL Server, creating indexes, stored procedures, and sometimes I don't know what I'm doing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Step 1 - drop the index `CODES_IS_COMM_IX` - it gives you nothing that `CODES_IS_TRANS_COMM_FLAG_IX` doesn't already have, but both indexes need to be maintained

Comment: @JNK I've updated my question with more screenshots. There is a `LCK_M_IX` lock. The last screenshot is a test with out `CODES_IS_COMM_IX` index.

Comment: I've removed all indexes except PK index and now it works perfectly.

Comment: That makes sense, as you're updating a column in an index and if that index is used by any other process it may contribute to a deadlock.